# Trying to break out of While Loop. Need to capture relative path of selected file from Dialog box

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I wrote a procedure to import 5 files into an Excel workbook. If the file is not found on the directory, then the an OpenFileDialog pops up to allow the user to browse for the file. If the user selects a file other than the one that is supposed to be imported, a warning pops up. Since there is a possibility that users select the wrong file more than once, I wrote a While Loop to keep checking for the right file name.

Up to there everything worked well. Here is where the issue comes in, If the file is not on the expected directory, say is on a CD, the user browses and finds the right file, and tries to open it, I still get the error message that the file is not the correct one. I figure out why, the While Loop is correct but the way I set my variables up is where the issue is.

My files are supposed to be located in the same path as my workbook so I set up my variables as follows:

```
Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim strImportFile As String
strImportFile = xlWBPath & "\" & GetImportFiles(n)
```

But because my missing file may be on a different directory my variable `strImportFile` is no longer valid, I have to now get the new path of the selected file and change, or declare a new variable. I have tried to do that on my code, but it is not working. Below is my code, I highlighted the area with the trouble:

```
Dim xlDestSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlWBPath As String = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim strImportFile As String
Dim xlWBSource As Object = Nothing
Dim xlWBImport As Object = Nothing


        'Loop through the 5 sheets and files

        For n As Long = 1 To 5 Step 1

            strImportFile = xlWBPath & "\" & GetImportFiles(n)
            xlDestSheet = DataSheets(n)

            'Convert the indexed sheet name to a string
            'so that it can be passed through the xlWB.Worksheets paramater

            Dim strDestSheetName As String = xlDestSheet.Name

            'If the file is found, then import, copy and paste the
            'data into the corresponding sheets
            If Len(Dir(strImportFile)) > 0 Then

                xlWBSource = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook
                xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                xlWBImport.Close()

            Else

                'If a sheet is missing, prompt the user if they
                'want to browse for the file.

                'Messagbox variables
                Dim msbProceed As MsgBoxResult
                Dim strVmbProceedResults As String = ("Procedure Canceled. Your project will now close")
                Dim strPrompt As String = " source file does not exist." & vbNewLine & _
                    "Press OK to browse for the file or CANCEL to quit"

                'If the user does not want to browse, then close the workbook, no changes saved.
                msbProceed = MsgBox("The " & GetImportFiles(n) & strPrompt, MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Question, "Verify Source File")

                If msbProceed = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
                    msbProceed = MsgBox(strVmbProceedResults, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

                    xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                    Exit Sub

                Else

                    'If the user does want to browse, then open the File Dialog
                    'box for the user to browse for the file

                    'Open Fil Dialog box variable and settings
                    Dim ofdGetOpenFileName As New OpenFileDialog()

                    ofdGetOpenFileName.Title = "Open File " & GetImportFiles(n)
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.InitialDirectory = xlWBPath
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.csv)| *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx; *.xlsm"
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.FilterIndex = 2
                    ofdGetOpenFileName.RestoreDirectory = True

                    'If the user presses Cancel on the box, warn that no
                    'file has been selected and the workbook will close

                    If ofdGetOpenFileName.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then

                        'Message box variables
                        Dim msbContinue As MsgBoxResult
                        Dim strAlert As String = ("You have not selected a workbook. The project will now close without saving changes")

                        'Once the user presses OK, close the file and do not save changes
                        msbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No Workbook Selected")
                        xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                        Exit Sub

                    Else

                        'If the user does select the file, then import the file
                        'make sure the right file was selected, if the wrong file is selected, issue warning
                        While strImportFile <> GetImportFiles(n)

                            Dim msbContinue As MsgBoxResult
                            Dim strAlert As String = ("The selected file is invalid. Please select file: " & GetImportFiles(n) & vbNewLine & _
                                                               " to continue.")
                            msbContinue = MsgBox(strAlert, MsgBoxStyle.RetryCancel + MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Wrong File Selection")

                            If msbContinue = MsgBoxResult.Cancel Then
                                xlWB.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

                                Exit Sub

                            Else
                                ofdGetOpenFileName.ShowDialog()

'*****Here is where I try to change the value of my 
'*****variable, but my loop still does not break.


                                Dim strGetPath As String = Nothing
                                strGetPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(ofdGetOpenFileName.FileName)

                                strImportFile = strGetPath & "\" & GetImportFiles(n)

                            End If

                            Continue While

                            If strImportFile = GetImportFiles(n) Then

                                Exit While

                                strImportFile = ofdGetOpenFileName.FileName
                                xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                                xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                                xlWBImport.Close()

                            End If


                            Try

                                'Import the remainder of the files
                                xlWBSource = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.ActiveWorkbook
                                xlWBImport = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(strImportFile)
                                xlWBImport.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy(xlWB.Worksheets(strDestSheetName).Range("A1"))
                                xlWBImport.Close()

                            Catch

                                MsgBox(Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Unexpected Error")

                            End Try
                        End While

      End If



                    End If

                End If



        Next



    End Sub
```

Comment: That's a big wall of code I just don't feel like wading through right now. Distilling your question down to just what's needed for the problem will help you get better answers faster. For that matter, it may help you solve this on your own. Breaking it apart into smaller methods is definitely better program design.

Comment: Did you watch with debugger the values of strGetPath , strGetPath ? It might be a "/" for a "\" or like.

Comment: It seems like you are not afraid of VS anymore ;) what is certainly a good thing. Although, as Joel rightly said, your problem is not clearly defined. Writing the whole code as a support can be helpful, but you shouldn't expect from us to analyse each bit of your code: isolate the wrong bit and tell the values you are getting under your specific conditions. Also make sure that all the involved variables are clearly defined (what is `GetImportFiles`?). It seems like you have set a loop whose point is not too clear: after `else` you should be analysing `ofdGetOpenFileName.FileName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't follow your code through completely but it seems that if you wanted a cheap and nasty way to get out of the loop, you could use:

```
For x As Integer = 1 to 1000
    If myString = "ExpectedResult" Then
        Goto ExitMyLoop
    End If
Next
ExitMyLoop:
```